# How to use the Nokia Imaging SDK's BlendFilter on WP8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I'm staring with the Nokia Imaging SDK to play a little with it. Now, I'm facing the problem where I have an Image which already exists (in a folder in my visual studio solution) and I want to convert this image in order to use it in the **BlendFilter** class of the **Nokia Imaging SDK**. However I don't know how to use it.

I was trying to convert the existing image in a stream and then pass it as a parameter to the **BlendFilter** constructor. But not luck. The compiler says that the best overload method match ... has some invalid arguments.

This is the way I'm trying to load the existing image to a stream:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/Template3.2.png", UriKind.Relative));

BitmapImage bitImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/Template3.2.png", UriKind.Relative));

WriteableBitmap Bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitImage);
```

And then:

```
var BlendFilter = new BlendFilter(bitImage, BlendFunction.Add);  --> the compiler error is here
```

Does anyone know how to use the **BlendFilter** class? any example would be very helpful.

Regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blend filter takes an IImageProvider as input. That means you can use any of the X-ImageSource classes as input and it will do all the work internally.

If you have a stream of the image I suggest you create an StreamImageSource and pass that to BlendFilter.

The list of different image sources is quite long, I suggest you look into the documentation and chose the one that is most appropriate to you.

Here is an example that takes a stream of an image as input, and blends a new image on top of it. For simplicity the other image is just an image filled with one color (ColorImageSource), but you can set any IImageProvider as source: chose the most convenient one.

```
using (var backgroundSource = new StreamImageSource(stream))
using (var filterEffect = new FilterEffect(backgroundSource))
{
    using (BlendFilter blendFilter = new BlendFilter()) 
    {
        var size = new Windows.Foundation.Size(400, 400);
        var color = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(250, 128, 255, 200);

        blendFilter.ForegroundSource = new ColorImageSource(size, color);
        blendFilter.BlendFunction = BlendFunction.Add;

        filterEffect.Filters = new[] { blendFilter };

        var result = await new JpegRenderer(filterEffect).RenderAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for sharing that code, I helped me to figure out how to do what I was looking for